# Avoid duplicates when updating records in CRM 2011 C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, dynamics-crm-2011, crm

I write application that retrieve record from CRM and update this record.
But when I run the "service.Update(...)", the record were duplicate (I saw it in the SQL Server DB).
I want to have only one record from specific Guid and now I have 2.

```
            foreach (DataRow row in rsltFromSql.Rows)
            {
                ActivityMimeAttachment attachmentMimeTemp = new ActivityMimeAttachment();
                try
                {
                    attachmentMimeTemp = (ActivityMimeAttachment)handlerCrm.CrmService.Retrieve(ActivityMimeAttachment.EntityLogicalName, Guid.Parse(row["ActivityMimeAttachmentId"].ToString()), new ColumnSet(true));
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    /////
                }

                //delete body field
                attachmentMimeTemp.Body = null;

                //update the attachment with body = null
                handlerCrm.CrmService.Update(attachmentMimeTemp);

                attachmentMimeGuidList.Add(new Guid(row["ActivityMimeAttachmentId"].ToString()));
            }
```

Comment: Do you have any other plugins or workflows that execute on update of ActivityMimeAttachment? And what are you doing with attachmentMimeGuidList? do you perform an update or create somewhere else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete the activityMimeAttachment and create a new one:

```
            //Retrieve ActivityMimeAttachment
            ActivityMimeAttachment attachmentMimeTemp;

            attachmentMimeTemp = (ActivityMimeAttachment)handlerCrm.CrmService.Retrieve(ActivityMimeAttachment.EntityLogicalName, Guid.Parse(row["ActivityMimeAttachmentId"].ToString()), new ColumnSet(true));

            //delete the old attachment (kit)
            handlerCrm.CrmService.Delete(ActivityMimeAttachment.EntityLogicalName, attachmentMimeTemp.Id);

            //create new attachment to the Email
            ActivityMimeAttachment newAttachment = new ActivityMimeAttachment
            {
                ObjectId = attachmentMimeTemp.ObjectId,
                ObjectTypeCode = "email",
                Body = System.Convert.ToBase64String(
                                new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes("Example Attachment")),
                FileName = String.Format("newFile")
            };
            handlerCrm.CrmService.Create(newAttachment);
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of creating new object instance of `ActivityMimeAttachment` just directly assign it return value from `Retrieve` method. like this:

```
foreach (DataRow row in rsltFromSql.Rows)
{
    ActivityMimeAttachment attachmentMimeTemp;
    try
    {
        attachmentMimeTemp = (ActivityMimeAttachment)handlerCrm.CrmService.Retrieve(ActivityMimeAttachment.EntityLogicalName, Guid.Parse(row["ActivityMimeAttachmentId"].ToString()), new ColumnSet(true));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
         /////
    }

    //delete body field
    attachmentMimeTemp.Body = null;

    //update the attachment with body = null
    handlerCrm.CrmService.Update(attachmentMimeTemp);

    attachmentMimeGuidList.Add(new Guid(row["ActivityMimeAttachmentId"].ToString()));
}
```